# Retrieving http response using spray and futures with timeout

Tags: scala, http, httprequest, spray

I am trying figure out the best way to retrieve the contents from a GET http request with using a timeout. I spent a good amount of time trying to figure out the best approach, but I am a little unsure.

Basically I just want to have an option that will return None if the response does not come before the timeout, otherwise return the contents.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the spray http client?

Comment: Yes, I am using Spray

Answer (score 1):

So I suppose you are trying to solve 2 problems. How to define a particular timeout in the configuration and then how to manage timeouts when they happen.

- Define http client timeouts: You will need to update your `application.conf` to overwrite the [default configuration of the http client](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/configuration/). e.g.:

  ```
  spray.can {
    client {
      request-timeout = 20s
    }
  }
  ```
- Managing timeouts: When you use the [spray client](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-client/), you will use a `pipeline` that will run the requests. It will be a function that looks something like `(HttpRequest) => Future[ObjectResponse]`.
  The result will be a `Future` of an object you have defined ,`ObjectResponse` in my example, you can resolve the future. In case a there is a timeout, the `Future` will become a [RequestTimeoutException](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/f6b029277a8156497bdc6ebd0d89505f322bd563/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/Http.scala#L137). Then you will be able to process the timeout exception with a `recover`. So your code will look something like this:

  ```
  def sendRequestFunction(...): Future[ObjectResponse] = {...}

  sendRequestFunction(parameters) map (Option) // In case we get an object, we will have a Some(obj)
  recover {
     case e: RequestTimeoutException => None
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
timedOutFuture = after(duration = duration, using = system.scheduler) {
   Future.successfull(None)
 }

Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(youHttpRequestFuture, timedOutFuture))
```

Hope it helps